# Show HTTP Request Parameters and Headers Being Sent To Server

Tags: android, android-studio

I am having an issue in my app, I need to be able to see or log the full network request so that I can see exactly what parameters are being posted to my server with what headers, currently it only shows me the URL, is there a way of doing this in android studio or is there some code I can write to display this data?

To further explain things seems the terms **network request**, **parameters** and **headers** are confusing people, I use the google volley library for all my htpp requests; GET, POST, PUT etc.  Now when posting data to a URL or getting data via a specific URL i need to be able to confirm that the right parameters and headers are being sent to the server.

Comment: debugging is for sure the easiest way to find out all parameters. Alternatively you can use a network analysis tool like Wireshark to get the full request. Most Android networking frameworks also have debugging capabilities themselves, though that depends on what you use obviously.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What paramters? Why can't you check which paramters are posted?

Comment: The parameters do not need to be named, I am sending a request both GET and POST, I need to know how to check the parameters being posted and the headers being sent in the http request.

Comment: @Phoca thank you, I am new to android so I'm not exactly familiar with the IDE, in web development I simply used firebug to do this but I have no Idea hod to do the same with the android studio IDE.

Comment: have several options: 1) use any debugging tools/proxies as people said 2) use interceptors(if available) of the HttpStack volley is using. OKHttp has option for that. 3) make a wrapper implementation of HttpStack which logs the request headers, additional headers and then delegates to the defult stack. 4) use https://github.com/apptik/jus and add a MarkerListener

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about testing the parameters for your API, you probably looking for REST clients like:

[Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)

[Rest Client](http://restclient.net/)

to validate services. But before that, you should have proper documentation of all the web services.

**Solution:**

In Android Studio, to debug your code, simply place breakpoints on the code and press **debug** button to execute

[image]

[image]

You can place breakpoint by clicking on left of each line where breakpoint is shown.

Also check this tutorial:
[Simple Debugging in Android Studio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vo5PXWnKtQ4) and follow further videos for proper debugging.

Comment: I do use postman to test my APIs.

Comment: so you want to check if you are sending right parameters through code ?

Comment: I want to determine that my app is indeed posting the right parameters and using the right headers when performing an HTTP request, if you have used firebug then should get what I mean, is there a similar functionality in android studio?

Comment: @user3718908 you got my point?

Comment: Through code after the request has been completed or through the network console if it has such capabilities.

Comment: @user3718908 Through code. check video tutorial for more help. place break point only where you want to debug.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use [OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp) for making all network calls. OkHttp provides [Interceptors](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors) which will serve your exact purpose.

Defining an interceptor:

```
class LoggingInterceptor implements Interceptor {
  @Override public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request request = chain.request();

    long t1 = System.nanoTime();
    logger.info(String.format("Sending request %s on %s%n%s",
        request.url(), chain.connection(), request.headers()));

    HttpUrl url = request.url(); // url of the request.

    Headers reqHeaders = request.headers(); // Here you are able to access headers which are being sent with the request.

    RequestBody body = request.body(); // provides body of request, which you can inspect to see what is being sent.

    Response response = chain.proceed(request);

    long t2 = System.nanoTime();
    logger.info(String.format("Received response for %s in %.1fms%n%s",
        response.request().url(), (t2 - t1) / 1e6d, response.headers()));

    Headers resHeaders = response.headers(); // Headers received in the response.

    return response;
  }
}
```

Using it to make network calls:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(new LoggingInterceptor())
    .build();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url("http://www.publicobject.com/helloworld.txt")
    .header("User-Agent", "OkHttp Example")
    .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
response.body().close();
```

Explore the [Interceptors](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors) for more customization.